# Laravel 5.5 Query Builder whereRaw returns no results but raw SQL does

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

When I perform the scoped query below I get no results, yet when I execute the resulting SQL (with bindings transcribed) on the database I get the expected results. I can query the model without the scope and the results are as expected.

It's a straightforward query checking whether a point exists within a polygon. I see no signs of errors or exceptions. I'm at a loss. Am I missing something?

### Area Class (w/ Query Scope):

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Grimzy\LaravelMysqlSpatial\Eloquent\SpatialTrait;
use Grimzy\LaravelMysqlSpatial\Types\Point;
use Grimzy\LaravelMysqlSpatial\Types\Polygon;
use Grimzy\LaravelMysqlSpatial\Types\Linestring;

class Area extends Model
{
    use SpatialTrait;

    protected $table = "areas";

    protected $spatialFields = [
        'point',    // MySQL POINT type
        'area'      // MySQL POLYGON type
    ];

    public function scopeContainsPoint($query, $lat, $lng) {
        return $query->whereRaw("ST_Contains(area, GeomFromText('POINT(? ?)'))", [$lng, $lat]);
    }

}
```

### Query Scope Usage and Results:

```
$s = Area::containsPoint(43.80, -79.48)->get();

=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3192
     all: [],
   }
```

### Eloquent Query Log:

```php
DB::getQueryLog();
=> [
     [
       "query" => "select * from `areas` where ST_Contains(area, GeomFromText('POINT(? ?)'))",
       "bindings" => [
         -79.48,
         43.8,
       ],
       "time" => 311.05,
     ],
   ]
```

### Resuting SQL (returns correct result):

```sql
select * from `areas` where ST_Contains(area, GeomFromText('POINT(-79.48 43.8)'));
```

Comment: To little information to help you, you should include the code also where and how you use scopeContainsPoint.. You sure you fetched the results after query building?

Comment: Thanks @Raymond, I've added the code snippet illustrating how I'm using the scope and retrieving results with `php artisan tinker`. I'm not sure what other information I can add but will gladly do so if it will help.

Comment: Can you also post the `Area` class code?

Comment: How are you manually running the SQL? Are you sure that it is the same DB, same user, same permissions, etc?

Comment: @Raymond - I've included the `Area` class code. I must reiterate that I can successfully run `Area::get()` and retrieve all current records in the table (which I can independently verify using Sequel Pro.

@Nigel - the permissions must be fine since I can retrieve all records without using the scope.

Comment: Please run the SQL in Laravel: `DB::select("select * from areas where ST_Contains(area, GeomFromText('POINT(?, ?)'))", [-79.48 43.8]);`

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir there was an error parsing that code. It looks like the comma should be in the array rather than between the point coordinates. I ran the following and got an empty array back: `DB::select("select * from areas where ST_Contains(area, GeomFromText('POINT(? ?)'))", [-79.48, 43.8]);`

Comment: The same query works on Sequel Pro?

Comment: Correct - the same statement pasted into Sequel Pro provides the record I am expecting. I also examined the `DB::getQueryLog()` output when executing the `DB::select` above and it produces the same SQL as in my original question. Very strange.

Comment: @russdot did you try running the outputted SQL as the Laravel user? I believe procedures have their own permissions in MySQL, that is the only possibility I see besides permissions by host or querying the wrong database.

Comment: @JoshRumbut - yes, I ran the SQL as the same user. I've confirmed the correct database as well, since I can retrieve all records using `Areas::get()`. The other thing I just found was that the builder is an instance of [`Grimzy\LaravelMysqlSpatial\Eloquent\Builder`](https://github.com/grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial/blob/master/src/Eloquent/Builder.php) but I don't think a select query executes the overridden `update()` method..

Comment: Can you create a http://sqlfiddle.com with some sample data?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir - I've created a fiddle, however the geometry fields are displaying as encoded: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9614c/2/0

Comment: Thanks everyone for your assistance and ideas. I finally tracked down the problem. It was an escaping issue that, for some reason, wasn't revealing itself on the `DB::getQueryLog()`. I've posted an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem boiled down to an issue escaping the `'POINT(-79.48 43.8)'` portion of the raw DB statement that for some reason didn't reveal itself on the `DB::getQueryLog()`.

Changing from:

```
$query->whereRaw("ST_Contains(area, GeomFromText('POINT(? ?)'))", [$lng, $lat]);
```

to this:

```
$query->whereRaw("ST_Contains(area, GeomFromText(?))", ["POINT($lng $lat)"]);
```

resolved the problem and returns the expected rows.

Edit:
Also, for anyone wondering - I discovered that the [Grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial](https://github.com/grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial/blob/master/src/Eloquent/SpatialTrait.php#L226) library contains the scope I was looking for (among many others). Still learned something about prepared statements though. Always read the manual.